# alternative to \paragraph in amsart

Tags: sectioning, sections-paragraphs, amsart

I have a mathematical proof which is long so I have split it up into different sections using \paragraph (eg. \paragraph{The first step}...)

In article mode, the text in the paragraph command is bolded and it stands out. In amsart, it does not and is useless. Can someone recommend me something standard I can use instead? I know I could manually bold the text but I'd rather do something standard.

I don't want to use a description environment because it indents everything and my equations break badly. Thank you.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper, reqno, draft]{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath, color, natbib}
\usepackage{amsfonts, mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
%\usepackage[amsmath, amsthm, hyperref]{ntheorem}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\esssup}{ess\,sup}
\swapnumbers
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{defn}[theorem]{Definition}
\newtheorem{lem}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{conjecture}[theorem]{Conjecture}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}

\DeclareMathOperator{\sign}{sign}
\newcommand{\cts}{\hookrightarrow}
\newcommand{\compact}{\xhookrightarrow{c}}
\newcommand{\mvec}[2]{\begin{pmatrix}#1\\\vdots\\#2\end{pmatrix}}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\begin{document}
\title{AA}
\author{AA}
\begin{abstract}
Blah
\end{abstract}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\makeatletter
\def\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}%
  \z@\z@{-\fontdimen2\font}%
  \normalfont\bfseries}
\makeatother
\section{Introduction}
\begin{theorem}We have $a=b$.
\end{theorem}
\begin{proof}The proof is split into two.
\paragraph{First step}Blah blah blah.
\paragraph{Second step}Blah blah blah
\end{proof}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{AA}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`amsart.cls` has

```
\def\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}%
  \z@\z@{-\fontdimen2\font}%
  \normalfont}
```

so if you put

```
\makeatletter
\def\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}%
  \z@\z@{-\fontdimen2\font}%
  {\normalfont\bfseries}}
\makeatother
```

in your preamble, it will use bold for paragraph heads.

Comment: Thanks for this but it does not work. Please see my code above. The output look like: ".First stepBlah blah blah". I tried putting your code before the begin{document} and after it, both the same result.

Comment: @christop try now:-)

Comment: Thanks it works. Can I ask was your first solution a typo or is it because I am using certain packages that it did not work?

Comment: @christop If your question had included a test document I'd have tested, but as it didn't I didn't: was just a typo, sorry. The 6th argument of `\@startsection` has no `{}` in the original but to put two commands there you need to brace them.

Comment: @christop but what egreg says is correct, this is misuse of `\paragraph` (which as the above code shows is a level **4** section heading only intended to be used after section, subsection, subsubsection)

Answer (score 5):

In my opinion you're abusing `\paragraph`. I'd prefer defining a command:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\proofstep}[1]{%
  \par% ensure starting on a new paragraph
  \addvspace{\medskipamount}% some vertical space
  \textit{#1\@addpunct{.}}\enspace\ignorespaces
}
\makeatother
```

Example.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{amsart}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\proofstep}[1]{%
  \par% ensure starting on a new paragraph
  \addvspace{\medskipamount}% some vertical space
  \textit{#1\@addpunct{.}}\enspace\ignorespaces
  %%% or comment the above and use
  % \textbf{#1\@addpunct{.}}\enspace\ignorespaces
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\title{AA}
\author{AA}
\begin{abstract}
Blah
\end{abstract}
\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\begin{theorem}
We have $a=b$.
\end{theorem}

\begin{proof}
The proof is split into two steps.

\proofstep{First step}
Blah blah blah.

\proofstep{Second step}
Blah blah blah
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I'd avoid boldface, because it would be too prominent with respect to the *Proof* label. The step name should definitely be indented for the same reason.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. I see what you mean. By the way, when you use the theorem environment and a subsubsection then the Theorem appears more prominent than the subsubsection which I think looks bad too. And subsection is equally as prominent as the Theorem. Anyway, I want to avoid indentation because my equations get too long and enter the margin.

Comment: @christop It's only the first line that gets intended with this code. And subsections being more subtle than theorems is a design decision of AMS that I quite like, but it's just a personal taste. In general, AMS articles come out usually very nicely looking.

Comment: @christop The `amsart` style is quite sluggish; it's not meant for producing real documents.

Comment: @tohecz ah that's great.

Comment: @egreg It seems though that on arXiv math papers (eg. Terrence Tao's) everyone uses amsart.

Comment: @christop This doesn't mean it's good in all of its parts. The usage of boldface, in particular, is inconsistent.

Comment: @egreg I agree. I wonder do you know of a better class? Or what do you use?

Comment: @christop For longer works I have my private class. Otherwise I use `article` with changes. The advantage of using a “private command” like `\proofstep` is that you can redefine it at will.

Answer (score 1):

Or use `xpatch`.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd{\paragraph}{\normalfont}{{\normalfont\bfseries}}{}{}

\begin{document}
\paragraph{Some paragraph}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: er doesn't that need to be `\normalfont\bfseries` in the replacement text?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle If I add `\normalfont`, it doesn't work in my miktex!. That is why. :(

Comment: You need  `\xpatchcmd{\paragraph}{\normalfont}{{\normalfont\bfseries}}{}{}` with extra `{}` (which were also missing from my answer, OP didn't provide a test file so I didn't test:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks, updated. I owe you a beer :-)